# Does setting an Option instance from Some to None trigger dropping of the inner value?

Tags: rust

I have the code:

```rust
struct Foo {}

impl Default for Foo {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // Do something
    }
}

fn main() {
    {
        let foo = Some(Foo::default());
        let foo = None; // Would this line trigger `Foo::drop`?
    };
    {
        let mut foo = Some(Foo::default());
        foo = None; // Would this line trigger `Foo::drop`?
    };
}
```

Are the resources occupied by `foo`s released properly?

The first situation (variable overwritten) will not trigger `drop`, so I added the second situation, in which I'm also confused.

Comment: Please write the edit reason, you've changed an important part of your code.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Yeah, I was doing.

Comment: It was called as shadowing, please read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227347/does-rust-free-up-the-memory-of-overwritten-variables

Comment: Why didn't you just put a `println` in your `drop` implementation and find out for yourself?

Comment: @Shepmaster I should :(. But anyway I learned a lot through this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> let foo = Some(Foo::default());
> let foo = None; // Would this line trigger `Foo::drop`?
> ```

No, the end of the block will.

Remember that `let` is a variable *declaration*, so the second line is not modifying the first `foo`, it is creating a new `foo` that shadows the former. But it still exists (and could be accessed if you created a reference to it before the second `let`) until the end of the block, so it will be dropped at end of the block.

If you want to actually change the variable, you have to do

```
let mut foo = Some(Foo::default());
foo = None;
```

Now it will trigger the drop immediately, because the old value is being overwritten, so it has to drop it.

Comment: In a hypothetical scenario, if you keep shadowing a variable like that in a loop (and loop is very long) does that have potential to "leak" quite a bit of memory until that end of block is reached?

Comment: @LoganReed You can't shadow a variable created in a loop in the loop itself -- you end up only shadowing the outer variable each iteration; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40323730/3650362) for example.

Comment: @LoganReed, the body of the loop is a block, so scope of any variable introduced in the loop ends at the end of iteration.

Comment: @trentcl, well you can have two `let foo`s in the body shadowing each other within one iteration—the point is their scope ends at the end of the iteration, so they don't accumulate.

Comment: @JanHudec - you are correct. To refine the question - is it dropped (and memory freed) at the end of each loop then, or do those shadowed variables stay on stack till the function ends (i.e. closing brace of the function, not the loop(!))? Rust docs say that stack gets freed only when function exits... If that is true - one can accumulate a lot of shadowed and no longer accessible variables on the stack.

Comment: @LoganReed, at the end of the loop body in each iteration. The only way things can accumulate on the stack is recursive function calls.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you explicitly notate your variable name as `_` it is dropped when the scope has finished.

In your case, variables will be released when the ***relevant scope*** is ended.

Since you implement `Drop` trait for `Foo` explicitly. It will override the `drop` behavior and call your `drop` function:

```rust
fn main() {
    let _: Option<Foo> = Some(Foo::default()); // Since variable name is '_' it will be dropped automatically.

    {
        let foo: Option<Foo> = Some(Foo::default());
        let foo: Option<Foo> = None;
        println!("Inner Scope Finishing. Going to drop inner scope variables.");
    } // Inner scope is finished dropping the inner scope variables.

    let main_foo: Option<Foo> = Some(Foo::default());
    let main_foo: Option<Foo> = None;
    println!("Main Scope Finishing. Going to drop main scope variables.");
} // Main is finished dropping the main scope variables
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7bae25b25fac55260422afadf274d978) to show the behavior.